# jQuery - Wrong price calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, woocommerce, elementor

I have this code in elementor custom code, it's loaded at the end of the body tag.

```js
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var productPrice;
    var finalProductPrice;
    var shippingPrice;
    var servicePrice;
    var result;
    var output;
    //
    $('#ship-price-a').on('click', function(){ 
          if( typeof productPrice === 'undefined' ){
                productPrice = $('#original-price').find('.woocommerce-Price-amount').text();
            }       
            //
          shippingPrice = $(this).attr('data-price');
        if( typeof finalProductPrice === 'undefined' ){    
                //var vat = ( shipPrice * 22 / 100 );
            finalProductPrice = ( parseFloat(productPrice) + parseFloat(shippingPrice) );
                result = finalProductPrice + '€';
            } else {
                var p = ( parseFloat(finalProductPrice) + parseFloat(shippingPrice) );
                result = p + '€';
            }
            output = result.replace('.', ',');
            $('#final-price').text(output);
            console.log('service price a click event - finalProductPrice',finalProductPrice);
    });
    //
    $('#ship-price-b').on('click', function(){
            if( typeof productPrice === 'undefined' ){
                productPrice = $('#original-price').find('.woocommerce-Price-amount').text();
            }       
      shippingPrice = $(this).attr('data-price');
            //var vat = ( shipPrice * 22 / 100 );
      if( typeof finalProductPrice === 'undefined' ){
                finalProductPrice = ( parseInt(productPrice) + parseFloat(shippingPrice) );
                result = finalProductPrice + '€';
            } else {
                var p = ( parseInt(finalProductPrice) + parseFloat(shippingPrice) );                                    
                result = p + '€';
            }
            output = result.replace('.', ',');
          $('#final-price').text(output);
            console.log('ship price b click event - finalProductPrice',finalProductPrice);
    });
    //
    $('#service-price-a').on('click', function(){
            servicePrice = $(this).attr('data-price');
            if( typeof productPrice === 'undefined' ){
                    productPrice = $('#original-price').find('.woocommerce-Price-amount').text(); 
            }
            if( typeof finalProductPrice === 'undefined' ){
                finalProductPrice = ( parseFloat(productPrice) + parseFloat(servicePrice) );
                result = finalProductPrice + '€';
            } else {
                var p = ( parseFloat(finalProductPrice) + parseFloat(servicePrice) );
                result = p + '€';
            }
            output = result.replace('.', ',');
            $('#final-price').text(output);
            console.log('service price a click event - finalProductPrice',finalProductPrice);
    });
    //
    $('#service-price-b').on('click', function(){
            servicePrice = $(this).attr('data-price');
            if( typeof productPrice === 'undefined' ){
                 productPrice = $('#original-price').find('.woocommerce-Price-amount').text();
            }
            if( typeof finalProductPrice === 'undefined' ){
                finalProductPrice = ( parseFloat(productPrice) + parseFloat(servicePrice) );
                result = finalProductPrice + '€';
            } else {
                var p = ( parseFloat(finalProductPrice) + parseFloat(servicePrice) );       
                result = p + '€';
            }
            output = result.replace('.', ',');
            $('#final-price').text(output);
            console.log('service price b click event - finalProductPrice',finalProductPrice);
    });
});
</script>
```

I'm facing an issue with it, it's supposed to calculate the final price of a product when the user click on some additional services that can be purchased.

For the `#ship-price-a` and `#ship-price-b` the calculation is done correctly. When the user try to add `#service-price-a` and `#service-price-b` the calculation will be wrong, only one of both services will be added to the calculation. Is there something wrong into the code and where I need to modify to fix?

Comment: This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: I don't have the code written locally so I can only use the dev console of the browser, anyway the problem seems with the `finalProductPrice` variable, once it will be set will remain with the same value and will not add the cost of other services

Comment: The code appears to only ever set a value to `finalProductPrice` if `typeof finalProductPrice === 'undefined'` is `true`.  So it appears to be explicitly *by design* that `finalProductPrice` will only ever be set to a value once and then never again...

Comment: Mainly I've done that check because I need a way to track the calculation, at the moment I'm setting the `finalProductPrice` when the user will click for the first time on one of additional services, then I will need to get back the value and add other costs to it.

Comment: Then what exactly are you asking?  If you've specifically defined the logic such that it only sets that value the *first time* the user clicks, why is it surprising that value is not updated on subsequent clicks?  Perhaps you could reduce this to a simpler [mcve] which demonstrates the problem as a [runnable code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/328193) and indicate specifically what isn't working as expected?

Comment: This is exactly the problem, after the variable is set, I will need to increment the value if other services are added. I've done the check because I was worried of a wrong increment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ictdev Yes, you can modify the code to prevent a service from being added multiple times and allow users to switch between different service options

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        var productPrice = null;
        var finalProductPrice = null;
        var shippingPrice = null;
        var selectedServices = {}; // Object to keep track of selected services
        var result;
        var output;
    
        function updateFinalPrice() {
            var totalServicePrice = 0;
            for (var key in selectedServices) {
                totalServicePrice += parseFloat(selectedServices[key]);
            }
    
            if (productPrice !== null) {
                finalProductPrice = parseFloat(productPrice) + parseFloat(shippingPrice || 0) + totalServicePrice;
                result = finalProductPrice.toFixed(2).replace('.', ',') + '€';
                $('#final-price').text(result);
            }
        }
    
        function getProductPrice() {
            if (productPrice === null) {
                productPrice = $('#original-price').find('.woocommerce-Price-amount').text();
            }
        }
    
        $('#ship-price-a, #ship-price-b').on('click', function(){ 
            getProductPrice();
            shippingPrice = $(this).attr('data-price');
            updateFinalPrice();
        });
    
        $('#service-price-a, #service-price-b').on('click', function(){
            getProductPrice();
            var serviceId = $(this).attr('id');
            selectedServices[serviceId] = $(this).attr('data-price'); // Add or update the selected service
            updateFinalPrice();
        });
    });
```

Comment: I didn't tested your second solution, can you comment the code to let me understand how it will work to prevent that items are added multiple times please?

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var productPrice = null;
    var finalProductPrice = null;
    var shippingPrice = null;
    var servicePrice = 0; // Initialize servicePrice as 0
    var result;
    var output;

    function updateFinalPrice() {
        if (productPrice !== null) {
            finalProductPrice = parseFloat(productPrice) + parseFloat(shippingPrice || 0) + servicePrice;
            result = finalProductPrice.toFixed(2).replace('.', ',') + '€';
            $('#final-price').text(result);
        }
    }

    function getProductPrice() {
        if (productPrice === null) {
            productPrice = $('#original-price').find('.woocommerce-Price-amount').text();
        }
    }

    $('#ship-price-a, #ship-price-b').on('click', function(){ 
        getProductPrice();
        shippingPrice = $(this).attr('data-price');
        updateFinalPrice();
    });

    $('#service-price-a, #service-price-b').on('click', function(){
        getProductPrice();
        servicePrice += parseFloat($(this).attr('data-price')); // service prices
        updateFinalPrice();
    });
});
```

1. Initialize servicePrice 0 to store services price.
2. Remove the arguments used to update the final price in a separate updateFinalPrice function.
3. Creating any shipment or value updates the finalProductPrice, ensuring that all selected transactions are added to the account.

Comment: why you have set `0` on service price?

Comment: Your suggested code seems working fine, I didn't considered to refactor the code to make it more clear, I'm not using jQuery from long time so I've missed some things of it. Thank you for the help

Comment: Setting servicePrice to 0 ensure prices starts from zero and adds up correctly if not defined the servicePrice  is set to undefined so that issues may arise

Comment: Just a question, I'm testing the code and will correctly add the services. Is there a way to avoid that a service can be added multiple time? For example if the user click the `ship-price-a` to add it but want to switch to `ship-price-b`, can be this done?